# Shared database on Heroku not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, heroku

I have app1 as:

```
~/Code/notifier/app1(master) $ heroku config
BUNDLE_WITHOUT      => development:test
DATABASE_URL        => postgres://abs-@ec2-50-19-213-76.compute-1.amazonaws.com/uobbhrmyhj
LANG                => en_US.UTF-8
RACK_ENV            => production
SHARED_DATABASE_URL => postgres://abs-@ec2-50-19-213-76.compute-1.amazonaws.com/uobbhrmyhj
~/Code/notifier/app1(master) $ heroku console
Ruby console for app1.heroku.com
>> User
=> User(id: integer, email: string, encrypted_password: string, reset_password_token: string, reset_password_sent_at: datetime, remember_created_at: datetime, sign_in_count: integer, current_sign_in_at: datetime, last_sign_in_at: datetime, current_sign_in_ip: string, last_sign_in_ip: string, confirmation_token: string, confirmed_at: datetime, confirmation_sent_at: datetime, created_at: datetime, updated_at: datetime)
>>
```

and app2 as:

```
~/Code/notifier/app2(master) $ heroku config
BUNDLE_WITHOUT      => development:test
DATABASE_URL        => postgres://abs-@ec2-50-19-213-76.compute-1.amazonaws.com/uobbhrmyhj
LANG                => en_US.UTF-8
RACK_ENV            => production
SHARED_DATABASE_URL => postgres://abs-@ec2-50-19-213-76.compute-1.amazonaws.com/uobbhrmyhj
~/Code/notifier/app2(master) $ heroku console
Ruby console for app2.heroku.com
>> User
NameError: uninitialized constant User
        /home/heroku_rack/lib/console.rb:150:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
        /home/heroku_rack/lib/console.rb:140:in `eval'
        /home/heroku_rack/lib/console.rb:140:in `_eval'
        /home/heroku_rack/lib/console.rb:73:in `block in process_command'
>>
```

they both have th esame database URL but "User" is not recognized in the second one. Following the Heroku newsletter, this should work.

Thanks

Comment: does your app work locally? Does it work on heroku with it's own DB?

Comment: Yes it does. As you can see from the example code, it works in app1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think the problem is at database level, but in the app2 app.

Comment: It sounds like that app2 cannot find the User model for some reason, this is before querying the database. If you open a rails console in the app2 directory and write User, what do you get?

Comment: It doesn't work because I don't have the User model. Maybe that's theproblem? However, given that the DB is shared, I thought I only needed to create in one of them. I can't do migrate twice?

Comment: app2 might be able to connect to the database no problems, but you are trying to use a class (User) that doesn't exists in your app. It needs to be implement even in app2. What's the goal here? If you want to reuse your existing models from app1 into app2 you might want to package your app as a gem and/or using engines (Rails).

Comment: I want to be able to access database of app1 to run some analytics on it. What's the goal of the shared db if I can't do that? Please explain. thansk

Comment: It's ok to have a shared database, but you need some code in your app2 to access the data through the ORM.
app1 and app2 are totally separate from my understanding as they does not contain the same code. Clearly the User class is not present in app2. The application that reads and writes from the database is entirely a different beast from the underlying database you have.

Comment: But if I create a model and a migration on app 2, won't that mess with the database? there's already a model there?